# Pandas read csv out of memory

Tags: python, csv, memory

I try to manipulate a large CSV file using Pandas, when I wrote this

```
df = pd.read_csv(strFileName,sep='\t',delimiter='\t')
```

it raises "pandas.parser.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: out of memory" 
wc -l indicate there are 13822117 lines, I need to aggregate on this csv file data frame, is there a way to handle this other then split the csv into several files and write  codes to merge the results? Any suggestions on how to do that? Thanks

The input is like this:

```
columns=[ka,kb_1,kb_2,timeofEvent,timeInterval]
0:'3M' '2345' '2345' '2014-10-5',3000
1:'3M' '2958' '2152' '2015-3-22',5000
2:'GE' '2183' '2183' '2012-12-31',515
3:'3M' '2958' '2958' '2015-3-10',395
4:'GE' '2183' '2285' '2015-4-19',1925
5:'GE' '2598' '2598' '2015-3-17',1915
```

And the desired output is like this:

```
columns=[ka,kb,errorNum,errorRate,totalNum of records]
'3M','2345',0,0%,1
'3M','2958',1,50%,2
'GE','2183',1,50%,2
'GE','2598',0,0%,1
```

if the data set is small, the below code could be used as provided by another

```
df2 = df.groupby(['ka','kb_1'])['isError'].agg({ 'errorNum':  'sum',
                                             'recordNum': 'count' })

df2['errorRate'] = df2['errorNum'] / df2['recordNum']

ka kb_1  recordNum  errorNum  errorRate

3M 2345          1         0        0.0
   2958          2         1        0.5
GE 2183          2         1        0.5
   2598          1         0        0.0
```

(definition of error Record: when kb_1!=kb_2,the corresponding record is treated as abnormal record)

Comment: No need to specify `delimiter` since `sep` is already provided. Also, `pd.read_table()` assumes `sep='\t'`, so you could just call that instead of `pd.read_csv()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your snippet in [out of memory error when reading csv file in chunk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30255986/out-of-memory-error-when-reading-csv-file-in-chunk),
 when reading line-by-line.

I assume that `kb_2` is the error indicator,

```
groups={}
with open("data/petaJoined.csv", "r") as large_file:
    for line in large_file:
        arr=line.split('\t')
        #assuming this structure: ka,kb_1,kb_2,timeofEvent,timeInterval
        k=arr[0]+','+arr[1]
        if not (k in groups.keys())
            groups[k]={'record_count':0, 'error_sum': 0}
        groups[k]['record_count']=groups[k]['record_count']+1
        groups[k]['error_sum']=groups[k]['error_sum']+float(arr[2])
for k,v in groups.items:
    print ('{group}: {error_rate}'.format(group=k,error_rate=v['error_sum']/v['record_count']))
```

This code snippet stores all the groups in a dictionary, and calculates the error rate after reading the entire file.

It will encounter an out-of-memory exception, if there are too many combinations of groups.

Comment: thanks, the combinations are not so many, I achieve the right thing, thanks for your help, this is a great solution

Answer (score 3):

You haven't stated what your intended aggregation would be, but if it's [just sum and count](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30242597/478288), then you could aggregate in [chunks](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#iterating-through-files-chunk-by-chunk):

```
dfs = pd.DataFrame()
reader = pd.read_table(strFileName, chunksize=16*1024)  # choose as appropriate
for chunk in reader:
    temp = chunk.agg(...)  # your logic here
    dfs.append(temp)
df = dfs.agg(...)  # redo your logic here
```

Comment: hi,thanks, I have edited my post to add the exact operation I want to have on the data

Comment: try:
 30         dfs = pd.DataFrame()
 31         reader=pd.read_table(strFileName, chunksize=1024*1024*1024)  # choose as appropriate
 32         
 33         for chunk in reader:
 34                 temp=tb_createTopRankTable(chunk)
 35                 dfs.append(temp)
 36                 df=tb_createTopRankTable(dfs)
 37     except:     
 38         traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)

Comment: line 33, in chunckRank
    for chunk in reader:
CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: out of memory
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: so it still run out of memory at line: for chunk in reader, my computer has 16G memory, so 1024*1024*1024 is not so big

Answer (score 2):

What @chrisaycock suggested is the preferred method if you need to sum or count

If you need to average, it won't work because `avg(a,b,c,d)` does not equal `avg(avg(a,b),avg(c,d))`

I suggest using a map-reduce like approach, with streaming

create a file called `map-col.py`

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
   print (line.split('\t')[col])
```

And a file named `reduce-avg.py`

```
import sys
s=0
n=0
for line in sys.stdin:
   s=s+float(line)
   n=n+1
print (s/n)
```

And in order to run the whole thing:

```
cat strFileName|python map-col.py|python reduce-avg.py>output.txt
```

This method will work regardless of the size of the file, and will not run out of memory

Comment: hi,thanks, I have edited my post to add the exact operation I want to have on the data

Comment: can you help on a solution? Since I met difficulty in  group by a 2.5 G file ,see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30255986/out-of-memory-error-when-reading-csv-file-in-chunk?noredirect=1#comment48617560_30255986